# How to redirect requests for index.php to /home with htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm currently using this method

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.mysite.com/home$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which works, but is there any way of getting the web root directory without entering it manually. So that the "http://www.mysite.com" part is replaced automatically. Just so that I can use this on my local server aswell as production without making changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes sure you can use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /home$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

target URI needs full site address with `http://` ONLY if your rule is redirecting to an outside URL but in this case you aren't.